# CMD START not working in Windows 8 for processor affinity

Tags: windows-8, cmd, command-prompt

I was trying to start my programs with processor affinity switch using the command prompt - this worked fine in windows 7 but does nothing to work in Windows 8.  It appears that everything after the CMD.EXE is completely ignored (except the ? switch)

Here's what I can't get to work: (note: it's a 6 core - so 48 equals cores 5 & 6 or 110000 mask)

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe start /affinity 48 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

I figured maybe the /affinity switch no longer worked, so I tried just the start switch only, but same results - a new command window opens and Firefox is not started (no programs work this way). Every combination I can think of - no luck!

Help?!

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes after `start`

```
start "" ...
```

For those that need more explanation, the start command takes the first double quoted string as the `title` and so as MC9000 found his command line opens the window and nothing appears to run.

The solution is to include empty quotes just after the `start` command (or to include any text within double quotes) as this null string or text will be the window title.

This start behaviour can change depending on content but the double quotes will always work.

Here are some examples:

```
start "" "c:\myfolder\myapp.exe"
```

and

```
start "" /NODE 1 /AFFINITY 0x3 "d:\folder\application1.exe"
```

Comment: Read the help for `start` and in particular the `title` - did you try it before arguing that it's not going to help?

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe start "" /affinity 48 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

no luck - the help is useless, hence why I ask

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" /affinity 48

no luck -

Comment: I've added further explanation for those that need it

Comment: Brilliant, this fixed a similar situation for me. Who would have thought?

Answer (score 0):

This did it - Can't have an empty title, affinity in Win 8 MUST be hex

```sh
START "FireFox" /AFFINITY 0x30 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Comment: For those who tried to set a shortcut to a program that sets the affinity automatically, here is the final string to enter into the "Target:" text box (this example is for FireFox to run on the last 2 cores of a 6 core processor)

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C START "FireFox" /AFFINITY 0x30 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Answer (score 0):

cmd /c start /AFFINITY 1 /D "C:\Program Files\myexe.exe